# Rails fonts not loading on mobile but showing on desktop

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, glyphicons, ionicons

As the title states, I have ionicons and pe font's in assets -> fonts folder.

In my application.rb file

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('/app/assets/fonts')
```

All icons work on desktop, that's pe and ionicons that are in my fonts folder as well as fonts from the gem 'font-awesome-rails'

[Website seen through Google Chrome on my desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws4Wv.png)

However, on mobile ALL fonts are seen as a blank box which suggest to me a 404 error but I don't understand what difference it would make whether its loaded from desktop or mobile.

[Website seen through Google Chrome on my iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZQRg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wrong way of importing font awesome in your CSS file. 
It tries to load them from `localhost:3000`:

[image: localhost_3000]

Because of that, the icons are visible on your computer (where the rails server is running) and they are not visible on your mobile phone.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for narrowing down the error to the way I am importing the files.

Comment: Turns out that I hadn't imported the css and javascript files required in the layout I was using for this particular page.